# How is Paths_pandoc.hs generated?

Tags: haskell, pandoc

In the project [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/), Paths_pandoc is imported in Shared.hs. Paths_pandoc.hs is located in dist/build/autogen/. How is it generated and what does it do for pandoc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a file that is generated by Cabal.

When you specify `Data-files:` in your `.cabal` file for your project, those files will be copied to a good location for "data files" on your system when you run `cabal install`. On Windows, this might be "C:\Program Files\Something" and on Linux it might be "/usr/share/something" (At least when you do a `--system` install).

Your code needs to know where the files were copied to, so Cabal generates that special module, which contains variables for the install paths that were used to copy the data files, so that your code can find the installed data files.

The module does also contain other information that Cabal provides for you, but the primary purpose of the module is what I just described.

See [this blog post](http://neilmitchell.blogspot.com/2008/02/adding-data-files-using-cabal.html) for more information.

Comment: One nit-pick I'd make: the files get copied over to a "data files" location whenever you use Cabal to install, even if you don't use cabal-install.